# Can SerialVersionUid be any number or does it have to be compiler generated?

Tags: java, serialization

If I write a serialversionUid for my class as say 1234, and I know that no other class in my program uses that, is that fine or do i always have to use a uid generated by the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

serialVersionUID can be any long that provides a unique signature to your object for serialization and deserialization. I don't think it even have to be unique. This is so that the serializer knows that that is the same Foo.class even after you have change the structure of the class. I typically use a -1L for the value.

Comment: Here is another reason to set your own serialVersionUID - http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article994.html

Comment: That's not correct. At best it's poorly stated. It doesn't have to be unique, as your own usage of -1L shows, and its function is not to 'uniquely identify your object'. Its function is to define its serialization signature, as the name implies.

Comment: EJP you are correct. It's a unique object signature for serialization. Thx

Comment: I didn't say that. It's not a 'unique object signature for serialization'. It does not have to be unique, and I *did* say that.

Comment: The combination of classname and serialVersionUID must identify (uniquely identify) the version of the class that was serialized.  For the purpose of serializaation, when unmarshaling (deserializing if you perfer) this combination is used as stated in the answer; to compair the class version that was serialized to the class version that is on the class path.

Answer (score 2):

It can be any number, at it only has to represent the version of that class. It does not have to be unique at all.